# WireGuard on CentOS with Android Client setup issues

Tags: centos, android, wireguard

I used [this guide here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-8-set-up-wireguard-vpn-server/) to setup wireguard on a CentOS machine.

I have my private key, my public key, the firewall and my wg0.conf:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.5.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 31194
PrivateKey = <from the private key file>
EndPoint = mydynamic_dns_name.com:31194

[Peer]
PublicKey = <the public key generated on my client>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.5.2/32
```

When I run `wg` it shows this config as well.
When I try to create a QR code with this config using the command

```
grep -v '^#' /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf | qrencode -t ansiutf8
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to import Tunnel: Unknown attribute in interface.
```

I tried to setup a client manually on Android, using this here:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.5.2/24
PrivateKey = <generated by the cellpgone>

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = mydynamic_dns_name.com:31194
PublicKey = <public key from my server>
```

When I try to connect, it says that it's connected instantly but transfers no data over the connection. When I check my external IP it's still that of the cell provider.

I have my router setup to forward the port to the centos in my local network.

I don't know how to proceed from here or to debug this.

Comment: You probably will need to connect via IPv6. The usability of IPv4 on mobile networks varies widely from full connectivity (very rare!) to only web sites work and only sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MichaelHampton but that can't be it, my OpenVPN setup with IPv4 is working fine.

Comment: OpenVPN is a totally different protocol on a different port. So maybe it can't be it, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: The wireguard on the CentOS side should know if the tunnel worked: `wg` should display `latest handshake: ...` with a recent time. Then you might still have routing issues in case android itself installs some `ip rule`. Maybe then trying from CentOS a `ping 192.168.5.2` would tell if something at all is working (a reply or nothing, but not `sendmsg: Destination address required`)